# Splitting a large network into many subgraphs using igraph

Tags: r, igraph, sna, subgraph

I have a large dataset comprising social network data from a number of different classrooms across different schools. I would like to split this large network into many smaller classroom networks according to a variable `"class_id"` or `"school_id"`. I am looking for a function similar to `split` for standard dataframes, which allows you to specify a factor `f` defining the number of groups. I have considered using the function `induced_subgraph` from the `igraph` package. However, looking at the package documentation, the function only contains the option `vids` where one should list the vertices that will form the subgraph. Is there a way to automate this process (perhaps using `lapply`) and specify the variable that induces the grouping? Alternatively, is there any other function capable of doing this?

Comment: Could you use `dput` to share your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(igraph)

net <- erdos.renyi.game(n= 100, p = .05) # generate random graph
class_id <- sample(1:5, 100, replace = T) # generate random groups

# create list of group memberships
class_id_list <- lapply(unique(class_id), function(i,j){
                        which(j %in% i)},
                        j = class_id)

# extract subnets based on group memberships
split.net <- lapply(class_id_list, function(net, v){
  induced_subgraph(net, vids = v)
  },
  net = net)
```